# Disabling checkboxes created using font-awesome

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, font-awesome

I am new to front-end technologies and want to achieve the below. I tried finding a solution but none has helped me till now.
My problem goes like this--
Suppose I have 2 master checkboxes labelled 
1) I do not like numbers
2) I do not like alphabets 
(both are using font-awesome styled checkboxes)

```
<div class="x-form-cb-li select-option2">
<input type="checkbox" name="brands" id="no-brand" style="display: none;">
<i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none; color:#228B22;"></i>
<label id="label-numbers" for="none" class="x-form-cb-label">I do not like numbers</label>
<label id="label-alphabets" for="none" class="x-form-cb-label">I do not like alphabets</label>
```

We have five checkboxes labelled 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 and when checkbox with label id="label-numbers" is checked these five checkboxes get disabled.
Similarly, we have five checkboxes labelled a, b, c, d and e and when checkbox with label id="label-alphabets" is checked these five checkboxes get disabled.
All these should use font-awesome icons. I was able to achieve this with normal checkboxes but am getting stuck with font-awesome ones.

**Edit:** Can somebody please help me with the code
https://jsfiddle.net/ankit1191/wb4snfm6/45/
In it when checkbox-'I do not like numbers' is checked, checkbox-'1' gets disabled and when unchecked checkbox-'1' comes to it's normal state.

Comment: The way you describe it looks like you should use radio buttons, see https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio you can make those into font awesome icons the same way as normal checkboxes.

Comment: @Jeremy I have added a comment to Pushpendra's answer. Hope it makes the question a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap class `disabled` in div with class `x-form-cb-li select-option2 disabled`. I think you are trying disable with bootstrap. Check disable class in bootstrap.

```
<div class="x-form-cb-li select-option2 disabled">
<input type="checkbox" name="brands" id="no-brand" style="display: none;">
<i class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check-square-o" style="display: none; color:#228B22;"></i>
<label id="label-numbers" for="none" class="x-form-cb-label">I do not like numbers</label>
<label id="label-alphabets" for="none" class="x-form-cb-label">I do not like alphabets</label>
```

Comment: disabled is not working here. Can you help me rectify this--> https://jsfiddle.net/ankit1191/wb4snfm6/35/. In it, I am struggling with the JS code, I want 1 and 2 to be disabled when checkbox-- 'I do not like numbers' is checked but a and b remain enables and unchecking it, again enables them. If first 2 master checkboxes are not selected, the remaining 1,2,a,b work without any conditions.